# MCMC method 1D Ferromagnetic Ising Model

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo, markov-chains

My question is related to the Python Coding of a 1-Dimensional Ising Model using a Markov Chain Monte Carlo method (MCMC).

I have the following Hamiltonian

```
$$H = - \sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\sigma_{i}sigma_{i+1} - B\sum_{i=1}^{L}\sigma_{i}$$
```

I want to write a python function that generates a Markov chain where at each step, it calculates and saves the magnetization (per site) and the energy.

The energy is (=Hamiltonian) and I will define the Magnetization as:

```
$$\frac{1}{L}\sum_{i}\sigma_{i}$$
```

My probability distribution would be:

```
$$p(x) = e^{-H\beta}$$ where, $T^{-1} = \beta$
```

For the Markov Chain I will implement a Metropolis-Hastings Algorithim;

```
if $$\frac{P(\sigma')}{P(\sigma)} = e^{(H(\sigma)-H(\sigma'))\beta}$$
```

My idea would be to accept transitions when

```
$$H(\sigma') < H(\sigma)$$
```

and to only accept transitions

```
$$H(\sigma') > H(\sigma)$$
```

with the probability

```
$$P = e^{(H(\sigma)-H(\sigma'))\beta}$$
```

So let me set a few parameters such as:

```
$L=20$ - Lattice Size

$T=2$ - Temperature

$B=0$ - Magnetic Field
```

I will need to plot a histogram of the magnetization and energy vs step size after the calculations. I have no issue with this part.

My python knowledge isn't great but I have included my rough (uncompleted) draft. I don't think I am making much progress. Any help would be great.

```
#Coding attempt MCMC 1-Dimensional Ising Model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Shape of Lattice L 
L = 20
Shape = (20,20)

#Spin Configuration
spins = np.random.choice([-1,1],Shape)

#Magnetic moment
moment = 1

#External magnetic field
field = np.full(Shape, 0)

#Temperature 
Temperature = 2
Beta = Temperature**(-1)

#Interaction (ferromagnetic if positive, antiferromagnetic if negative)
interaction = 1

#Using Probability Distribution given
def get_probability(Energy1, Energy2, Temperature):
  return np.exp((Energy1 - Energy2) / Temperature)

def get_energy(spins):
    return -np.sum(
    interaction * spins * np.roll(spins, 1, axis=0) +
    interaction * spins * np.roll(spins, -1, axis=0) +
    interaction * spins * np.roll(spins, 1, axis=1) +
    interaction * spins * np.roll(spins, -1, axis=1)
  )/2 - moment * np.sum(field * spins)

#Introducing Metropolis Hastings Algorithim
x_now = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)    #initial value
d = 10**(-1)                               #delta
y = []
for i in range(L-1):
      #generating next value
      x_proposed = np.random.uniform(x_now - d, x_now + d)
      #accepting or rejecting the value
      if np.random.rand() <  np.exp(-np.abs(x_proposed))/(np.exp(-np.abs(x_now))):
          x_now = x_proposed
      if i % 100 == 0:
          y.append(x_proposed)
```

Comment: I'm very familiar with the Ising model simulation and I think this code isn't right. Try to search for Ising models in Phyon thought the internet.

Comment: I have researched the internet for a while and can't find any clear coding help. They all relate to the 2D model. I understand the idea of the code and the math behind it, just not how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I changed your code to solve the problem the way I always do.

Please, check the code and formulas very carefully

```
#Coding attempt MCMC 1-Dimensional Ising Model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Shape of Lattice L 
L = 20
#Shape = (20)

#Number of Monte Carlo samples

MC_samples=1000

#Spin Configuration
spins = np.random.choice([-1,1],L)
print(spins)
#Magnetic moment
moment = 1

#External magnetic field
field = 0

#Temperature 
Temperature = 2
Beta = Temperature**(-1)

#Interaction (ferromagnetic if positive, antiferromagnetic if negative)
interaction = 1

#Using Probability Distribution given
def get_probability(delta_energy, Temperature):
  return np.exp(-delta_energy / Temperature)

def get_energy(spins):
    energy=0
    for i in range(L):
        energy=energy+interaction*spins[i-1]*spins[i]
    energy= energy-field*sum(spins)
    return energy
def delta_energy(spins,random_spin):
    #If you do flip one random spin, the change in energy is:
    #(By using a reduced formula that only involves the spin
    # and its neighbours)
    if random_spin==L:
        PBC=0
    else:
        PBC=random_spin+1
    
    return -2*interaction*(spins[random_spin-1]*spins[random_spin]+
              spins[random_spin]*spins[PBC]+field*spins[random_spin])

#Introducing Metropolis Hastings Algorithim
#x_now = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)    #initial value
#d = 10**(-1)                               #delta
#y = []

magnetization=[]
energy=[]
for i in range(MC_samples):
    #Each Monte Carlo step consists in L random spin moves
    for j in range(L):
        #Choosing a random spin
        random_spin=np.random.randint(L-1,size=(1))
        #Compuing the change in energy of this spin flip
        delta=delta_energy(spins,random_spin)
        
        #Metropolis accept-rejection:
        if delta<0:
            #Accept the move if its negative
            spins[random_spin]=-spins[random_spin]
        else:
            #If its positive, we compute the probability
            probability=get_probability(delta,Temperature)
            random=np.random.rand()
            if random<=probability:
                #Accept de move
                spins[random_spin]=-spins[random_spin]
                
                
    #Afer the MC step, we measure the system
    magnetization.append(sum(spins)/L)
    energy.append(get_energy(spins))
print(magnetization,energy)

#Do histograms and plots
```

At the end of the simulation, the variables magnetization and energy are arrays that contain the measured values at each MC step.
You can directly use these arrays to compute the histograms and plots.

Note: The energy array, is the total energy of the system, not the energy/L.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simple implementation of a 1D Ising model, and came across this post. While I am no expert on the field, I did write my masters on a related topic. I implemented the code in Oriol Cabanas Tirapu's answer, and found a few bugs (I think).

Below is my adapted version oh their code. Hopefully it is useful for someone.

```
#Coding attempt MCMC 1-Dimensional Ising Model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Using Probability Distribution given
def get_probability(delta_energy, Temperature):
    return np.exp(-delta_energy / Temperature)

def get_energy(spins):
    energy=0
    for i in range(len(spins)):
        energy=energy+interaction*spins[i-1]*spins[i]
    energy= energy-field*sum(spins)
    return energy

def delta_energy(spins,random_spin):
    #If you do flip one random spin, the change in energy is:
    #(By using a reduced formula that only involves the spin
    # and its neighbours)
    if random_spin==L-1:
        PBC=0
    else:
        PBC=random_spin+1
        
    old = -interaction*(spins[random_spin-1]*spins[random_spin] + spins[random_spin]*spins[PBC]) - field*spins[random_spin]
    new = interaction*(spins[random_spin-1]*spins[random_spin] + spins[random_spin]*spins[PBC]) + field*spins[random_spin]
    
    return new-old

def metropolis(L = 100, MC_samples=1000, Temperature = 1, interaction = 1, field = 0):
    
    # intializing
    #Spin Configuration
    spins = np.random.choice([-1,1],L)
    
    Beta = Temperature**(-1)
    
    #Introducing Metropolis Hastings Algorithim
    data = []
    magnetization=[]
    energy=[]
    for i in range(MC_samples):
        #Each Monte Carlo step consists in L random spin moves
        for j in range(L):
            #Choosing a random spin
            random_spin=np.random.randint(0,L,size=(1))
            #Compuing the change in energy of this spin flip
            delta=delta_energy(spins,random_spin)

            #Metropolis accept-rejection:
            if delta<0:
                #Accept the move if its negative
                spins[random_spin]=-spins[random_spin]
                #print('change')
            else:
                #If its positive, we compute the probability
                probability=get_probability(delta,Temperature)
                random=np.random.rand()
                if random<=probability:
                    #Accept de move
                    spins[random_spin]=-spins[random_spin]

        data.append(list(spins))

        #Afer the MC step, we measure the system
        magnetization.append(sum(spins)/L)
        energy.append(get_energy(spins))
        
    return data,magnetization,energy
    
    
def record_state_statistics(data,n=4):
    ixs = tuple()
    
    sub_sample = [[d[i] for i in range(n)] for d in data]
    
    # get state number
    state_nums = [int(sum([((j+1)/2)*2**i for j,i in zip(reversed(d),range(len(d)))])) for d in sub_sample]
    
    return state_nums



# setting up problem
L = 200 # size of system
MC_samples = 1000 # number of samples
Temperature = 1 # "temperature" parameter
interaction = 1 # Strength of interaction between nearest neighbours
field = 0 # external field

# running MCMC
data = metropolis(L = L, MC_samples = MC_samples, Temperature = Temperature, interaction = interaction, field = field)
results = record_state_statistics(data[0],n=4) # I was also interested in the probability of each micro-state in a sub-section of the system

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.imshow(np.transpose(data[0]))
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.axis('tight')
plt.ylabel('Space',fontdict={'size':20})
plt.title('Critical dynamics in a 1-D Ising model',fontdict={'size':20})


plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(data[2],'r')
plt.xlim((0,MC_samples))
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.ylabel('Energy',fontdict={'size':20})
plt.xlabel('Time',fontdict={'size':20})
```